# scrapy xpath exception

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

```
    self.product_urls.extend(hxs.select("//div[@id="product-list"]//div[@class="product-images"]/table/tr[1]//a')").extract())
```

This line of code gives me an exception "Invalid Path", I guess it's something wrong with "product-list"
how can I write the same @id without getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with Extra parentheses , here is correct syntax.

```
self.product_urls.extend(hxs.select('//div[@id="product-list"]//div[@class="product-images"]/table/tr[1]//a').extract())
```

google should be your best friend for this kind of issues, you need to learn Xpath/python basics as well

Comment: Thanks I found out this :) I thought before that list is somehow a reserved word in python which is not. Thanks :)